# Unable to generate tree using a JS function

Tags: javascript, xml, recursion

Why the function **buildTree** does not iterates over the whole xml ?

Below is the code for xml and JS:

```js
var response = "<scope><friend><name>Alex</name><hobbies><h>music</h><h>salsa</h></hobbies></friend><friend><name>Natasha</name><hobbies><h>hiking</h></hobbies></friend></scope>";

function buildTree(data) {
  treePart = "";
  treePart += "<ul>";
  if (data.children.length != 0) { 
    for (i = 0; i < data.children.length; i++) {
        treePart += "<li>" + data.children[i].tagName + "<span>[-]</span>";
        treePart += buildTree(data.children[i]);
        treePart += "</li>";
     }
    treePart += "</ul>";
  }
  else {
    treePart += "<li>" + data.innerHTML + "</li>";
  }
  treePart += "</ul>";
  return treePart;
}

parser = new DOMParser();
xml = parser.parseFromString(response, 'text/xml');

x = buildTree(xml);
document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<ul>
    <div id="app"></div>  
</ul>
```

As can be seen in the code snippet, this node doesn't get displayed.

```
<friend><name>Natasha</name><hobbies><h>hiking</h></hobbies></friend>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (i = 0 ...`
If you don't declare `i` with "var" or "let", it assumes the global scope:
when it finishes iterating over the `h` tags, `i=2`, so when it goes back up to iterate over the second `friend` tag, `i < data.children.length` is false and it stops there.

```js
var response = "<scope><friend><name>Alex</name><hobbies><h>music</h><h>salsa</h></hobbies></friend><friend><name>Natasha</name><hobbies><h>hiking</h></hobbies></friend></scope>";

function buildTree(data) {
  treePart = "";
  treePart += "<ul>";
  if (data.children.length != 0) { 
    // Initialize i with "var" or "let"
    for (var i = 0; i < data.children.length; i++) {
        treePart += "<li>" + data.children[i].tagName + "<span>[-]</span>";
        treePart += buildTree(data.children[i]);
        treePart += "</li>";
     }
    // That's one too many </ul>
    //treePart += "</ul>";
  }
  else {
    treePart += "<li>" + data.innerHTML + "</li>";
  }
  treePart += "</ul>";
  return treePart;
}

parser = new DOMParser();
xml = parser.parseFromString(response, 'text/xml');

x = buildTree(xml);
document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<ul>
    <div id="app"></div>  
</ul>
```